# Changing height of linearlayout dynamically on drag

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set height of linearlayout dynamically but i need to call requestlayout always which fliker's the layout.Is any solution for this below is the code for dragging.

```
 moreLoadingPullToRefreshView.setOnDragListener(View.OnDragListener { v, event ->
            val action = event.action
            when (event.action) {
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED ->
                    // do nothing
                    Log.d("***started", "started drag")
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                    Log.d("***continued", "drag continued")
                    val x_cord = event.x.toInt()
                    val y_cord = event.y.toInt()
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
                    Log.d("***ended", "drag end")
                    val mCurX = event.x.toInt()
                    val mCurY = event.y.toInt()
                    Log.d("****location stated", "Cur(X, Y) $mCurX, $mCurY")
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
                    val mCurX = event.x.toInt()
                    val mCurY = event.y.toInt()
                    val ll:LinearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.loaderView)
                    ll.getLayoutParams().height = mCurY;
                    ll.requestLayout();
                    Log.d("****location stated", "Cur(X, Y) $mCurX, $mCurY")
                }
                else -> {
                }
            }
            true
        })
```